# Fancy Box V 2.1.3 is not loading dynamic images through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a Script where I call the fancy box to load the images. When place the static Urls, images are loading. But when I place the variable that contains the url data which is returning from the ajax fancy box is not showing the images. Instead it is showing the error "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

My code snippet is

$.ajax({

```
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: '/admin/cms/sliders/get-stylebook-images',
data:'pid='+pageId,
success: function(data){
if(data.output!='')
{
    alert(data.output);                 
    $.fancybox([data.output], {
                    'padding': 0,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'type'  : 'image',
                    'changeFade' : 0,
                    'topRatio'    : 0.2
                     });
}
else
{
    $.fancybox(['http://www.xxxx.com/gallery-spring-summer/01.jpg'], {
                    'padding': 0,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type'  : 'image',
        'changeFade' : 0,
        'topRatio'    : 0.2
        });  
    }
}
```

});

In the above snippet when I alerted the data.output urls is showing as 'http://www.xxxxx.com/Uploads/Images_path/abc.jpg'. But placing the data.output in the fancybox showing error. If I copy the URL from alert and place it in the fancybox it is working flawless.

I have tested Fancy box V2.1.5 also. But there is not use. I have tested it with both JQuery V1.8.1 and V1.4.1. But there is no use.

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: try `$.fancybox( [{ href: data.output }], { ....`

Comment: I have tried that, but it is nor working in that way also. Small note there could be chance to get more than one URL from ajax. like 'xxxx.com/one.jpp','xxxx.com/two.jpg','xxxx.com/three.jpg', etc.